# About absolute value

Tags: linear-algebra

Just a conceptual problem; I'm sorry if this question is a duplicate or anything.
I know that:
$x^2 = \pm\sqrt{x^2} = |\sqrt{x^2}|$
Why then, considering the function $f(x)= |x|$, $f(x) >0$ or $f(x)= 0$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the definition of absolute value which is $|x|=x$ if $x \ge 0$ but $|x|=-x$ if $x \lt 0$
Thus there is no way you will get a negative, because if you are $\lt 0 $ you will multiply by negative one, thus becoming positive again.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer